# Tried to install boot camp and now can’t get into my Mac OS hard drive

Tags: mac, hard-drive, bootcamp

So I installed boot camp and then couldn’t get windows to boot. So I ran a program called “gdisk” which I must have given the wrong instructions to.

Now I can’t access my Mac OS hard drive, but it looks like the data is still there in disk0. I have attached a picture of my “diskutil list” from recovery mode. Can anyone help me get it back to the right parameters?

[image]

Comment: Add the output from `fdisk  /dev/disk0`

Answer (score 1):

The partition information for macOS appears to be stored in the MBR partition table. You will need to manually copy the values from this table to a newly created GUID Partition Table (GPT).

1. Boot to Internet Recovery mode.
2. Open a Terminal application window.
3. Use command below to printout the values in the MBR table.

   ```
   fdisk /dev/disk0
   ```
4. Use the `gpt` command to create a GPT with the partition entries.

I would give more detailed instructions, but I would first need to see the output from `fdisk`.